# How can I define an HKT for instance (over object) methods in Scala?

Tags: scala, monads, traits, higher-kinded-types

How do you define an HKT in Scala to provide methods, such as `map`, as methods on instances instead of functions on objects?

I know you can

```
trait M[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](f: F[A])(fn: A => B): F[B]
}

object Q extends M[Q] {
  def map[A, B](f: Q[A])(fn: A => B) = new Q(fn(f.e))
}

class Q[A](val e: A)

Q.map(new Q(1))(_.toDouble)
```

However, I want to use `map` on instances instead. I haven't seen any literature that does this, so I've written the following.

```
trait M[A, F[A]] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): F[B]
}

class Q[A](val e: A) extends M[A, Q] {
  def map[B](f: A => B) = new Q(f(e))
}

new Q(1).map(_.toDouble)
```

Is it idiomatic Scala? Does it do what `map` should do? Are there limitations compared with the object version above? (An aside, with `extends M[A, Q[A]]` it won't compile - why?)

I have seen

```
trait M[A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): M[B]
}
```

but then `Q`'s `map` could return a `class R[A] extends M[A]` which isn't desired.

Comment: So, you want a **typeclass**. The idea is that there is only one instance of the typeclass for your type, because here the relation ship is `Q _has_ an instance of M` instead of `Q _is_ an instance of M`. Usually, in **Scala**, those instances are made implicit, so you can use them without having to pass them manually. Additionally, one usually defines an implicit `Ops` or `Syntax` class _(like Joe K did)_ to provide the **functions** of the typeclass with a regular **method** notation, just to make their use more natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a library specifically for this: https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum

You can also do it yourself. The typical pattern is to define a corresponding implicit `MOps` class or whatever:

```
trait M[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](f: F[A])(fn: A => B): F[B]
}

implicit class MOps[F[_] : M, A](x: F[A]) {
  def map[B](f: A => B): F[B] = implicitly[M[F]].map(x)(f)
}
```

Then example usage:

```
case class Box[A](a: A)

implicit val BoxM = new M[Box] {
  def map[A, B](f: Box[A])(fn: A => B): Box[B] = Box(fn(f.a))
}

Box(2).map(_.toString)
```

But it's a lot of boilerplate, so simulacrum does it all for you (and more).

Comment: so you define the map as per the object version then use implicits to give that functionality to the instance?

Comment: what implications are there for this approach compared to mine?

Comment: Your approach allows for some weird things like `class Foo[A] extends M[A, Bar]`. This is a common problem, I think this is the best write-up I've seen about it: http://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

Comment: Also, some methods of some typeclasses don't have instances associated with them, e.g. Monoid's `empty` method. So these typeclasses have to use this style of representation, and once you start having a few of this form, you often want inheritance (`Monoid[A] extends Semigroup[A]`) and pretty soon it's easier to do everything this way